# how to request protobuf using volley?

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, android-volley

anyone has an example, where you read a protobuf, using volley?. I have read that you can implement ProtobufRequest class, but I can not find documentation for it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I have done it,the work is ok,hope it is helpful.first create the ProtobufRequest class like below that extends Request,Request is the basic request class in Volley,then,you can create the custom request extends ProtobufRequest that do custom doParse().just as a reference.

RequestData is SomeProto message,

```
private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 30000;

/** Content type for request. */
private static final String PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/x-protobuf";

private static final Object sDecodeLock = new Object();

private RequestData mRequestData;
private BaseCallback mCallback;

public ProtobufRequest(RequestData data, BaseCallback callback) {
    super(Method.POST, Constants.SERVER_URL, callback);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mRequestData = data;
    mCallback = callback;
    this.setRetryPolicy(getRetryPolicy());
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Charset", "UTF-8");
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-protobuf");
    headers.put("Accept", "application/x-protobuf");

    return headers;
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE;
}

@Override
public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy() {
    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(SOCKET_TIMEOUT,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    return retryPolicy;
}

    /**
    ** write the protobuf data to http request,it is very important
    */
@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    if (mRequestData == null) {
        return super.getBody();
    } else {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {

            baos.write(mRequestData.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return super.getBody();
        }

        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(Object arg0) {
    mCallback.onResponse(arg0);
}

    /**
    ** parse the response result
    */
@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    synchronized (sDecodeLock) {
        try {
            return doParse(response, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
}

abstract protected Response<T> doParse(NetworkResponse response, Entry entry)


public interface BaseCallback extends Listener<Object>, ErrorListener {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

From: [cmcneil](https://github.com/cmcneil/volley-protobufrequest/blob/master/ProtoBufRequest.java/) Added code in case link rot. There should be an official implementation by Volley or Protocol Buffers eventually so please update this when necessary.

```
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Response.Listener;
import com.android.volley.RetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;
import com.google.protobuf.MessageLite;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by carson@convox.org on 5/10/15.
 */
 public class ProtoBufRequest<ReqT extends MessageLite, RespT extends MessageLite> extends Request<RespT> {

    private ReqT request;
    private final Class<RespT> responseType;
    private final Listener<RespT> listener;
    private static final String PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/x-protobuf";
    private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 30000;

    public ProtoBufRequest(int method, String url, ReqT data, Class<RespT> responseType,
                           Listener<RespT> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = listener;
        this.request = data;
        this.responseType = responseType;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Charset", "UTF-8");
        headers.put("Content-Type", PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE);
        headers.put("Accept", PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE);

        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        if (request == null) {
            return super.getBody();
        }
        return request.toByteArray();
    }


    @Override
    protected Response<RespT> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            if (responseType == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The response type was never provided.");
            }
                RespT responseInstance = responseType.newInstance();
                return (Response<RespT>) Response.success(
                        responseInstance.newBuilderForType().mergeFrom(response.data).build(),
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy() {
        RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(SOCKET_TIMEOUT,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        return retryPolicy;
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(RespT response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not an example and I have not (yet) done it myself but here is how I would do it:

One way is to extend JsonObjectRequest and serialize and deserialize every protocol buffer as Json using:

```
 Message someProto = SomeProto.getDefaultInstance();
 String jsonFormat = JsonFormat.printToString(someProto);

Message.Builder builder = SomeProto.newBuilder();
String jsonFormat = _load json document from a source_;
JsonFormat.merge(jsonFormat, builder);
```

See: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-java-format/

Otherwise, if you want to send the protocol buffer serialize to byte[] you could extend `Request<T>`. The you would override `public byte[] getBody()` for the request body/payload, and
protected `Response<Message> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)` for the answer.

You would then use the following functions to serialize the protocol buffer.

```
byte[] toByteArray();

parseFrom(byte[] data);
```

If you have a solution do not forget to share.

Answer (score -1):

Just sticking this here in case it's useful:
I searched around a lot for a generic way to do something similar to [jeff wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3349968/jeff-wang)'s answer. I couldn't find anything so I wrote this.
Let me know if you have any way to get rid of the unchecked cast in there...

ProtobufRequest.java

> ```
> public class ProtoBufRequest<ReqT extends Message, RespT extends Message> extends Request<RespT> {
>
>   private ReqT request;
>   private final Class<RespT> responseType;
>   private final Listener<RespT> listener;
>   private static final String PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/x-protobuf";
>   private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 30000;
>
>   public ProtoBufRequest(int method, String url, ReqT data, Class<RespT> responseType,
>                          Listener<RespT> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
>       super(method, url, errorListener);
>       this.listener = listener;
>       this.request = data;
>       this.responseType = responseType;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
>       Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
>       headers.put("Charset", "UTF-8");
>       headers.put("Content-Type", PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE);
>       headers.put("Accept", PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE);
>
>       return headers;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
>       if (request == null) {
>           return super.getBody();
>       }
>       return request.toByteArray();
>   }
>
>
>   @Override
>   protected Response<RespT> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
>       try {
>           if (responseType == null) {
>               throw new IllegalArgumentException("The response type was never provided.");
>           }
>               RespT responseInstance = responseType.newInstance();
>               return (Response<RespT>) Response.success(
>                     responseInstance.newBuilderForType().mergeFrom(response.data).build(),
>                       HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>           return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
>       }
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public String getBodyContentType() {
>       return PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy() {
>       RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(SOCKET_TIMEOUT,
>               DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
>       return retryPolicy;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   protected void deliverResponse(RespT response) {
>       listener.onResponse(response);
>   } 
> }
> ```